# Spring Boot 2.5.x: Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have a file uploading api which was working perfectly fine under the `spring boot` version `2.1.13`. After upgrading the version to `2.5.2`, it started to throw an exception. Looking at the changelogs, I couldn't see anything significant changes that's related to `Multipart` processing. What could I be missing here? Below are the sample codes I have.

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:161) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB
```

**controller end point**

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "/upload", 
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
...
}
```

**Request Payload Sample**

```
POST http://localhost:8080/upload
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGG9dgUb5THDV0eDB

------WebKitFormBoundaryGG9dgUb5THDV0eDB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Sample.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundaryGG9dgUb5THDV0eDB--
```

**Note:** I don't have any `MultipartResolver` bean defined in my configuration. I tried adding the MultipartResolver bean definition as follows (only one at a time) but didn't seem to resolve the issue.

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() { // didn't work
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}

@Bean
public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() { // didn't work
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out this issue was affected after the `Spring Boot 2.2`. Since that version, the filter `HttpHiddenMethodFilter` was disabled by default. The issue got fixed after enabling the filter in `application.properties`.

```
spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true
```

**My Findings in Detail**

The purpose of the above filter has nothing to do with the error I was getting. But the request `parts` was getting initialized as a side effect of executing the filter. More specifically, when the filter tries to retrieve the `_method` parameter value `(e.g. request.getParameter("_method")`, the `getParameter` method of the `request` instance internally seems to parse the parameters which then initializes the request `parts`. So when the filter was disabled in `spring-boot` version 2.2, there was nothing to initialize the request `parts`.

I feel like the request `parts` initialization should be fixed within the `Spring` framework itself. But until then, either we could enable the `HttpHiddenMethodFilter` filter, or we could define a custom filter that takes care of initializing the request `parts`, something like below:

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RequestInitializerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.getParameterNames(); // this takes care of initializing request `parts`

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestPart` has `required=true` as default (take a look to the documentation). It seems that the `HttpHiddenMethodFilter` initialize the value as a sideeffect. The spring update change this behavior.
To fix this, set `required=false` and initialize the value if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@ManojShrestha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1158189/manoj-shrestha)'s comment. I don't know why but in my case, I don't need to config `hiddenmethod` in `application.properties`. I just add custom filter class. But anyway, it worked.