# Spring boot form data uploading file not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

for context, i'm creating a file upload/download restful service, and was testing in postman, i'm getting an error that i'm not supposed to.

This is my *Document Entity*

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "t_document")
public class Document extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "data", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private byte[] data;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "file_type")
    private String fileType;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_id")
    private ApplicationEntity applicationEntity;
}
```

`BaseEntity` just implements serializable and nothing more.

These are my Service and ServiceImpl classes

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public interface DocumentService {

    Document saveDoc(MultipartFile file, String title) throws Exception;

    Document getDoc(int id);
}
```

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Service
public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService{

    @Autowired
    private DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    @Override
    public Document saveDoc(MultipartFile file, String title) throws Exception {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try{
            if(fileName.contains("..")){
                throw new Exception("Filename contains invalid path sequence "+fileName);
            }
            Document fileEntity = Document.builder()
                                    .title(title)
                                    .name(fileName)
                                    .fileType(file.getContentType())
                                    .data(file.getBytes())
                                    .build();
            return documentRepository.save(fileEntity);
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception("Could not save File:" +fileName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Document getDoc(int id) {
        return documentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

And this is my controller class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/recruiter")
public class RecruiterLandingPage {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentService documentService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<String>> Hello(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(ApiResponse.of("Recruiter's landing page"));
    }

    @PostMapping("/candidate/uploadDocument")
    public DocumentResponse uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        Document document = null;
        document = documentService.saveDoc(file, "title");

        String downloadUrl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                                    .fromCurrentContextPath()
                                    .path("/download/")
                                    .path(Integer.toString(document.getId()))
                                    .toUriString();

        return new DocumentResponse(
                document.getName(),
                downloadUrl,
                file.getSize()
        );

    }
    @PostMapping("/candidate/name")
    public String returnName(@RequestParam("name") String name) throws Exception {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And when i run it on postman i get this
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhHQK.png)

```
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Required part 'file' is not present.",
    "instance": "/user-service/recruiter/candidate/uploadDocument"
}
```

even though i'm passing the file in the form data option in postman.
curl from postman

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8080/user-service/recruiter/candidate/uploadDocument' \
--form 'file=@"/C:/Users/user/Downloads/Doc - Wireframe.docx"'
```

---

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Could you please share with Repository interface, wanna write the same code on me, thanks, if can you tell, you use simple save method from JPARepository?

Comment: What is the log printed in the console ? Update the error log.

Comment: The same code totally works on me. Little difference is, I removed @Lob and columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB" from Entity Class and I use import javax.persistence.*; not jakarta

Comment: Check your version of Spring boot -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765889/spring-boot-2-5-x-required-request-part-file-is-not-present

Comment: Thank you for the responses guys, figured out the error. Our company actually has a base template, which every project has to start from, and it was recently updated, so, it was their issue, i had to scour to hundreds of thousands of lines of code, and then found this stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom request filter, tempered with the curl response which caused the error.